How to make material that is only visible when there is an object behind?
I want to figure out how to make material in EEVEE for this plane that blends transparent and diffuse in a way that it only is opaque when there's an object behind it.

So from camera's perspective scene looks like this:

And plane's material makes it so the scene looks like this:


Do you need it to be in shading ? It would be quite simple in compositing.

@Lutzi yep definitely need it in shading however could you provide the compositing way as well? This might be very useful in different projects

I honestly don't even know if this is possible to do in shading. It's generally hard to pass data between different objects in the shader. It's dead simple to do in compositing. Just put your objects in different collections, and make those visible on different view layers:

Make them visible on each layer by checking this box on the collections.


Then after rendering you composite it together like this.

The cryptomatte is picking the front objects material, or you can do the object ID. Enable that under the View Layer properties panel.

